# How to put form data into json file in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am creating an application where I have to add the contacts from a form input. I want to add data from the form input field to my JSON file.

Unfortunately I am not able to find any solution for it until now. Kindly help in this regard. This is my controller code where the JSON object is also defined. I want to fetch the data from input filed to the JSON object array.

```js
var contactManager = angular.module('contactManager', ['ngAnimate']);

// Contacts List Controller
contactManager.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
    //$scope.contacts = 'name';
  });
}]);

// Contacts Details Controller
contactManager.controller('DetailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {

    $scope.contact = [{
        "name": "Stephen Radford",
        "phone": "0123456789",
        "address": "123, Some Street\nLeicester\nGH1 2SR",
        "email": "stephen@email.com",
        "website": "stephenradford.me",
        "notes": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Alan Border",
        "phone": "154648445",
        "address": "457, Some Street\nBirmingham\nLM1 2AB",
        "email": "stephen@email.com",
        "website": "alanborder.me",
        "notes": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "Misbah ul Haq",
        "phone": "8899556744",
        "address": "458, Some Street\nFaisalabad\nFD1 2MH",
        "email": "misbah@email.com",
        "website": "misbah.me",
        "notes": ""
      }
    ];

    $scope.contactId = $routeParams.contactId;

    $scope.addNew = function() {

      $scope.contact.push($scope.newData);
      $scop.newData = null;
      $scope.added = true;
    };
  }
]);
```

This is my form code. Where I am taking the input from a form

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="addNew()" ng-controller="DetailsController">
  <input ng-model="contact.name">
  <input ng-model="contact.phone">
  <input ng-model="contact.address">
  <button>Click here to store data</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide full controller code.

Comment: var contactManager = angular.module('contactManager', ['ngAnimate']);

// Contacts List Controller
contactManager.controller('ListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('js/data.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.contacts = data;
    //$scope.contacts = 'name';
  });
}]);

Comment: I am able to read the data successfully. But not able to post the data in the file.

Comment: Show me the POST request.

Comment: You will need a server api to edit/add data to a file.

Comment: Can you provide any plnker or fiddle link ?

Comment: $scope.addNew = function(){  
  $scope.companies.push({ 'name':$scope.name, 'employees': $scope.employees, 'headoffice':$scope.headoffice });
  // Writing it to the server
  //  
  var dataObj = {
    name : $scope.name,
    employees : $scope.employees,
    headoffice : $scope.headoffice
  }; 
   
  // Making the fields empty
  //
  $scope.name='';
  $scope.employees='';
  $scope.headoffice='';
 };
}]);

Comment: @Saqib do not update/write code in comments.Please use edit button to update your question.

Comment: @Navoneel Now i have updated the code. If you could take some time to help me out please.

Comment: @BharathKumar I have updated my code. Can you now help me please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the object to data `storedata` function.

```
<button ng-click="storedata(obj)">Click here to store data</button>
```

Than, you can do it whatever you want.

```
$scope.storedata = function(obj) {
   // obj is json
   $post('/path_to_server', obj);
};
```

Comment: Where is the storedata function?

Comment: Just below it in the javascript (stored in the `$scope`.